# Debugging PHP in Ubuntu (Xdebug)

Tags: apache2, php, debugging, debug, xdebug

PHP Vim Debugger: Configuring Apache

I am trying to install [Vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug) to debug PHP in Vim. Unfortunately, when I press F5 this message appears after a few seconds

```
Waiting for a connection (Ctrl-C to cancel, this message will self-destruct in
20  seconds...)
No connection was made
```

What should I do?

I searched about this in Google, followed this [tutorial](http://uw-freelancer.github.io/blog/vim-vdebug/) and [this](http://ccpalettes.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/remote-debugging-php-with-vim-and-xdebug/) one (and many others) but did not work.

I followed Vdebug [instructions](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/blob/master/doc/Vdebug.txt).

I do not know how to achieve this:

```
Edit your apache configure file

In your VirtualHost section, set debugger port same as the one in your vimrc:

php_value xdebug.remote_port **9009**
```

The remote_port that has just been mentioned is different from what I have in xdebug.ini and vimrc. Please, see below.

Right now I have in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1         
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp     
xdebug.remote_mode=req         
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/media/www/xdebugdata
```

And in my vimrc

```
let g:vdebug_options = {}
let g:vdebug_options["port"] = 9000
```

I installed [Xdebug helper Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) too. Using an IDE is not an option: I wish to use Vim.

Comment: just FYI but your php_value xdebug.remote_port points to 9009 whereas your xdebug.remote_port=9000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it and now Vdebug is working.

Enable xdebug in PHP
Edit your php.ini file and add the following under the "Module Settings" section:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

zend_extension=/path/to/my/xdebug.so

[debug]

; Remote settings

xdebug.remote_autostart=off

xdebug.remote_enable=on

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.remote_host=localhost

xdebug.remote_port=9000

; General

xdebug.auto_trace=off

xdebug.collect_includes=on

xdebug.collect_params=off

xdebug.collect_return=off

xdebug.default_enable=on

xdebug.extended_info=1

xdebug.manual_url=http://www.php.net

xdebug.show_local_vars=0

xdebug.show_mem_delta=0

xdebug.max_nesting_level=100

;xdebug.idekey=

; Trace options

xdebug.trace_format=0

xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp

xdebug.trace_options=0

xdebug.trace_output_name=crc32

; Profiling

xdebug.profiler_append=0

xdebug.profiler_enable=0

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0

xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp

xdebug.profiler_output_name=crc32
```

Try it out

Everything should be ready to go now. Restart apache and run phpinfo() to see if any xdebug information comes up. If it doesn't, then the apache error_log + google are your friends.

Otherwise, you are ready to run the debugger inside vim.

Open a PHP script in VIM that you can access from your localhost
Open that same PHP script in your web browser
Add F5. You should see at the bottom of VIM like "waiting for a new connection on port 9000 for 10 seconds..."
Within the next 10 seconds, refresh the browser page with the `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1` on the end of the URL.
Go back to VIM and you're in the debugger in all its glory.
Don't forget: to switch between windows in VIM, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>.

[Source -it applies to Ubuntu though it refers to another linux distribution-](http://jasonmaur.com/vim-xdebug-and-php-53-compiled-from-source-on-arch-linux/)

Hope this helps.